# Duration time between cycles in a log file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sh

My apologies if this is too basic, but I have a log with this kind of information:

```
Mai  5 12:34:00 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|xoengineMain.cpp:122|0xb88ec60] starting xoengine 4.0.1.2 (x86) from [/usr/bin/xoengine]
Mai  5 12:35:00 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|DataStorage.cpp:1370|0xb88ec60] loading database [/var/xoengine/xoengine.db]
Mai  5 12:35:10 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|DataStorage.cpp:2043|0xb88ec60] database loaded in 40ms
Mai  5 12:37:00 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|xoengineMain.cpp:318|0xb88ec60] xoengine is running
Mai  7 10:32:00 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|xoengineMain.cpp:122|0xb88ec60] starting xoengine 4.0.1.2 (x86) from [/usr/bin/xoengine]
Mai  7 10:32:58 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|xoengineMain.cpp:152|0xb88ec60] demo licensed for 5 machines expiring on 2017-10-04
Mai  7 10:33:00 xoengine XO[1287]: [Xo|xoengineMain.cpp:318|0xb88ec60] xoengine is running
```

My intention is geting something like this:

```
    Cycle: 1 Duration: 00:03:00
    Cycle: 2 Duration: 00:01:00
    ...
```

the time is calculated on the basis of finding in the lines the words "starting" and "running" and so calculate the time it took between the "starting" and "running"
Thanks

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35230264/3776858

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code I wrote, and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/var/log/file.log"
countStart=0
countStop=0

getDuration()
{
  read -r h m s <<< $(echo $1 | tr ':' ' ' )
  echo $(((h*60*60)+(m*60)+s))
}

while read line; do

   if [[ $line =~ 'starting xoengine' ]]; then
      starting=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
      START=$(getDuration $starting)
      let countStart+=1
   elif [[ $line =~ 'xoengine is running' ]]; then
      stopping=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
      STOP=$(getDuration $stopping)
      let countStop+=1
   fi

   if [ $countStart -eq $countStop ] && [ $countStop -ne 0 ]; then
      DIFF=$((STOP-START))
      echo "Cycle $countStart Duration: $((DIFF/60))m $((DIFF%60))s"
   fi

done < $logfile
```